# Issue opening jQuery UI datepicker with current date

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using jQuery UI datepicker.

```
<input id="sent_date" type="text" value="01/01/2001">
```

Initialized like this.

```
$( "#sent_date" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFOrmat: "mm/dd/yy",
    defaultDate: new Date()
});
```

Now the datepicker opens at "01/01/2001". If I change my JavaScript like this

```
$( "#sent_date" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFOrmat: "mm/dd/yy",
    defaultDate: new Date()
}).datepicker("setDate", 0);
```

Now the datepicker opens at "11/08/2013". But my textbox also change to "11/08/2013"
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/3KutM/

So, my question is,

How can I *open my datepicker with today's date* (11/08/2013), *without altering the displayed textbox date*(01/01/2001)?

Comment: Set the date in the datepicker's `beforeShow:` function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `beforeShow` option to update the date when the datepicker is opened.

```
$( "#sent_date" ).datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFOrmat: "mm/dd/yy",
    beforeShow: function(el, dp) {
        dp.datepicker("setDate", 0);
    }
});
```

Comment: I am sorry if my question was not clear enough. `$(el).datepicker("setDate", "0");.datepicker("setDate", "0");` wont work. I do not want to change the `input.value`

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a way to separate the date that's in the input from the date that the datepicker opens on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is no afterShow method in JQuery UI DatePicker after all. As monkey-patching seemed a little far-fetched, ended up using the beforeShow and onClose event in tandem like this.

```
var elm = {}, oldDate = "";
$(".dp-date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFOrmat: "mm/dd/yy",
    defaultDate: new Date(),
    beforeShow: function (el, dp) {
        elm = $(el);
        oldDate = $.trim(elm.val());
        elm.val("");
    },
    onClose: function (dateText, dp) {
        if ($.trim(elm.val()) === "") {
            elm.val(oldDate);
        }
        oldDate = "";
    }
});
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/4KSKr/